# Parse notifications not working with AdHoc provisioning profile

Tags: ios, parse-platform, notifications, provisioning-profile

I know this question has been asked a few times but I am still having issues after trying all the suggested fixes.

I have an app that is being tested through Apple's TestFlight of which a number of External Users have downloaded. The app was built using an AdHoc Distribution Profile against the relevant App ID which has Push Notifications Enabled for Distribution and has the necessary Apple Push Services certificate. I am using Parse and am able to receive notifications on my test device (signed with the dev certificate and APN push cert), however the external testers are not receiving any notifications.

I am using Parse and can see in the logs that the notifications are being sent so I am assuming it is something with the devices themselves related to a problem with the provisioning profiles. I also followed the steps to uploading a new .p12 file to my Parse server for production notifications.

However, it seems that only the builds with the development profile are able to receive notifications. Am I correct in assuming that this is because the certificate used by Parse to sign the notification doesn't match that which was used in the adhoc build? I.e. Parse is still using the old .p12 certificate?

When I uploaded the new .p12 file to my Parse server I didn't explicitly remove the previous .p12 certificate, do I need to do this? Would revoking the dev APN certificate solve this?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled **Push Notification** from capabilities ?

Comment: Yes. The capabilities are set to Enabled for both Development and Distribution.

Comment: I mean from Xcode not from you developer account.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Otherwise the development build would not receive push notifications?

Comment: what is the iOS version in which you are checking your development build ?

Comment: The device running the dev build is on 10.1

Comment: On parse you can upload multiple .p12, so upload certificate for dev and ad hoc both

Comment: This is what I have done. I have uploaded both certificates yet adhoc builds are not receiving notifications.

Comment: I think I have identified the issue. When uploading the production .p12 file to my Parse server I did not change the production setting from false to true. I will test this and mark as solved if it is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason notifications were not being received was due to the production flag not being set to true when I uploaded the production certificate to my Parse server. I re-uploaded the certificate setting this to true and notifications began to work.